# why this error occurs 'reset modules states' in odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I am getting this error in odoo10 enterprise?
any suggestions to solve this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoodev/odoo10Enter/la10e/addons/base/ir/ir_cron.py", line 285, in _acquire_job
    cls._process_jobs(db_name)
  File "/home/odoodev/odoo10Enter/la10e/addons/base/ir/ir_cron.py", line 222, in _process_jobs
    odoo.modules.reset_modules_state(db_name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reset_modules_state'
2019-09-23 04:52:19,215 3048 WARNING ? odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_cron: Exception in cron:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoodev/odoo10Enter/la10e/addons/base/ir/ir_cron.py", line 285, in _acquire_job
    cls._process_jobs(db_name)
  File "/home/odoodev/odoo10Enter/la10e/addons/base/ir/ir_cron.py", line 222, in _process_jobs
    odoo.modules.reset_modules_state(db_name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reset_modules_states'
```

Comment: Post the code causing the error.

Comment: @Guy  if datetime.now() - oldest > MAX_FAIL_TIME:
                    odoo.modules.reset_modules_state(db_name)

Comment: Is this a default Odoo cron job? Did you migrate Odoo to another version? I can't see anything in the official Odoo runbot instances.

Comment: no, i did not migrate Odoo to another version.

Comment: Can you explain the scenario, are you trying some custom modules ?

Comment: After upgrading a custom module i am continuously getting this error. and i cannot uninstall it because all  custom data will lost